# Переделать C++ template в Java generic

Tags: java, generics

как написать этот кусок кода на С++ в Java:

```
template <typename T1, size_t N>
class tensor : public array<T1,N> {
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прямого аналога, думаю, не получится. В качестве параметров у java generic могут быть только типы. <size_t N> никак не переписать на Java.
Как-то так

```
public class Tensor<T> extends ArrayList<T> { // typename T1 - T
    public Tensor(int n) { // size_t N - параметр конструктора n
        super(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) super.add(null);
    }
    ...
}

...

Tensor<MyClass> tensor = new Tensor<>(10);
```

У ArrayList на самом деле размер не фиксирован, задаётся только начальная ёмкость.
Можно/нужно самому переопределить стандартные методы (add, remove там...) для "фиксации" размера.
Или найти готовые решения. Может быть получится приспособить FixedSizeList из Apache Commons Collections.

Comment: да это я уже понял. Каким образом это реализовать. Я подумываю попробовать через абстрактные классы это провернуть. Стоит ли пытаться? Или тут я тоже в тупик зайду

Comment: На самом деле не понятно зачем нужен этот тензор. С какой целью в него заворачивается array? Нельзя обойтись обычным массивом или списком?

Comment: намек понял. попробую еще покопаться в коде и учебниках). Я просто плюсов не знаю и смотрю на них с позиции Java.